# How do I parse a CSV where each row is enclosed in square brackets using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I've stumbled across a CSV-ish format whilst trying pass a feed received from Transport for London. What would be the best method to parse this using PHP?

http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?circle=51.49288,-0.147425,100&ReturnList=StopPointName,EstimatedTime,StopID

```
[4,"1.0",1418639278611]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639472000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639395000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639397000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639696000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639742000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639731000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418640051000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639938000]
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far ? I'll suggest you read about : [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: What about replacing [ and ] with empty char ""?

Comment: I just wanted to get the ID after the station name so I tried

//Expression to remove the square brackets
$contents = preg_replace( '/\[.*?\]/', '', $contents );

//Explode by line breaks
$Rows = str_getcsv( $contents, "\n" );

//Explode 2nd row
$Values = str_getcsv( $Rows[1], "," );

return $Values[2];

but I get blanks. Maybe a problem with my preg_replace?

Comment: Sorry for the messy paste, new to SO. Basically I tried explode by row and then exploding by comma (using str_getcsv to get quotes). @Alex I've handled JSON Objects before, is this some kind of JSON array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each row *individually* looks like JSON, you could use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) here:

```
// input as string
$input = '....';

// split by lines
$lines = explode( "\n", $input );

// walk through results
for( $i=0; $i<count($lines); $i++ ) {

  // parse row
  $row = json_decode( $lines[i] );

  // do something with it ...

}
```

Comment: Please, read the file line by line... I can't see any reason to read the whole file and then split it to access each line  :|

Comment: @Sirko I will suggest `foreach` in this case.

Comment: @VitorLima Depends on how OP got the input. It is nowhere stated that this is a file.

Comment: @Sirko You are right, I just commented it because if he will read from a file, it's better change little things, for example, the main loop...

Answer (score 1):

After parsing each row into separate strings you could use [substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp) to trim the brackets.

for instance:

```
echo substr("1418639472000]",0,-1);
> 1418639472000
```

and

```
echo substr("[1234",1);
> 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an associative array for each line

```
$file = file('http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?circle=51.49288,-0.147425,100&ReturnList=StopPointName,EstimatedTime,StopID');

array_walk($file, function(&$line) {
    $line = json_decode($line);
    if (count($line) == 3) {
        $line = array_combine(array('id', 'count', 'timestamp'), $line);
    } else {
        $line = array_combine(array('id', 'station_name', 'station_id', 'timestamp'), $line);
    }
});

print_r($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make iterated calls of `json_decode()`. Because the strictly formatted string is VERY nearly valid json, you only need to replace newlines with commas, then wrap that single string in square braces, then `json_decode()` is ready to gobble up the string and spit out an indexed array of indexed arrays.  Note, on some systems, you may need to replace `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/42CKW))

```
$bracedCSV = <<<CSV
[4,"1.0",1418639278611]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639472000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639395000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639397000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639696000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639742000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639731000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418640051000]
[1,"Eccleston Bridge","35312",1418639938000]
CSV;

var_export(
    json_decode('[' . str_replace("\n", ',', $bracedCSV) . ']')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => '1.0',
    2 => 1418639278611,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639472000,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639395000,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639397000,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639696000,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639742000,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639731000,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418640051000,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Eccleston Bridge',
    2 => '35312',
    3 => 1418639938000,
  ),
)
```